# fopen on DVD Ram on windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, fopen, dvd

I have  a problem with **fopen** on **DVD Ram** on windows 7.

When i open a file ( binary or test file) on DVD Ram.

Contents of file  wasn't discarded and the file wasn't  treated as a new empty file when size of file is <**1833** bytes.

If size of file >=**1833**, its is ok.

It only happen on DVD Ram and windows 7 ( HDD, USB or windows XP is ok)

Please help me

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE             *_stream;  

    _stream = fopen( "G:\\Test",  "wb" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When use fopen with mode "w+":
write/update: Create an empty file and open it for update (both for input and output). If a file with the same name already exists its contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file.

But with file has size <1833 Bytes, contents of file wasn't discarded.
Do you know reason?

Comment: check the return value of `fopen` and if it's `NULL`, also check `errno`. It might indicate  the reason...

Comment: @Naytzyrhc: `fopen` can't know whether you're going to write <1833 bytes later. The failure probably happens on a flush.

Comment: @Thien Phuc: Sounds like an OS-level bug. What **file system** is on the DVD-R? Can you copy an 1024 byte file to that DVD using Explorer?

Comment: This bug exist on USB.  
Format USB to UDF
Use command: format <driveLetter>: /fs:UDF /q
If use fopen file has size is < 297 bytes.


On USB: 296 = 512- 216 => 512 is one sector on USB
On DVD: 1832 = 2048-216 => 1204 is one sector on DVD

Comment: @MSalters: I can copy an 1024 byte file to that DVD using Explorer. I use a normal file